# Xcode build error clang failed

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, clang, mapbox

Something's missing in my iPhone application.

I do not success to fix this error, that seams to be a martian error for me...
I do not understand at all, even after many searches...

```
ProcessPCH /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/IntraMuros-Prefix-etlohrlrqzwcjicedfazzdvoaqbq/IntraMuros-Prefix.pch.pth IntraMuros/IntraMuros-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd "/Users/xyz/iOS - Applications/intramuros-ios/Application"
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/IntraMuros.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntraMuros.build/IntraMuros-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/IntraMuros.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntraMuros.build/IntraMuros-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/IntraMuros.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntraMuros.build/IntraMuros-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/IntraMuros.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntraMuros.build/IntraMuros-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/xyz/iOS -I- -IApplications/intramuros-ios/Application/IntraMuros/Vendors/mapbox-ios-sdk -I/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/IntraMuros.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntraMuros.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/IntraMuros.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntraMuros.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator --serialize-diagnostics /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/IntraMuros-Prefix-etlohrlrqzwcjicedfazzdvoaqbq/IntraMuros-Prefix.pch.dia -c "/Users/xyz/iOS - Applications/intramuros-ios/Application/IntraMuros/IntraMuros-Prefix.pch" -o /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/IntraMuros-Prefix-etlohrlrqzwcjicedfazzdvoaqbq/IntraMuros-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IntraMuros-cqmesmesegqjxofftymiymllpzow/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/IntraMuros-Prefix-etlohrlrqzwcjicedfazzdvoaqbq/IntraMuros-Prefix.pch.d

clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I use the mapbox project for this application, maybe is it related, but I do not think about it ?!

What is really strange is that the other iOS developper of the project can build and run without problem, with the same code... We are versionned by Github.

Does anyone has allready seen this type of bug ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a stray `-` in an `Header Search Paths` setting in your xCode project.

Unfortunately, there isn't a particularly easy way to find this except for looking through the document using the project viewer (you could edit it with a text editor, but that could worsen the problem).

Basically, select the project document in the Project Navigator (left pane) and then look through the project's Build Settings, and then the Build Settings for each target in turn, looking for the `Header Search Paths` setting and anywhere it shows up as bold, you will want to double-click and make sure there isn't a single `-` (or a `-` followed by a space or comma, which could be parsed as a single argument).

If you don't locate it this way, you may have a build setting that is resolving to `-`, so look at the bottom of the Build Settings and make sure there isn't a User-Defined variable that is set to `-` (or `-` or `-,`).

Comment: My God !!!!!

There it was !

I had a - in any parent folder of the project, and this was the problem's source...


Thank you a lot for this, I was going crazy !

Answer (score 0):

Either in the prefix or the linker flags, you've told clang to process a flag named -I-, which is not a valid flag.  Remove it and build again.

Comment: I do not find this flag on my settings, do you know where it could be ?

Comment: What architectures are you building for (armv6/7), and what does the build setting look like?