# Unable to successfully build a project on Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I'm trying to build a project on Xcode 8.2.1 but with no success. Getting this error,

> clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead

I'm not able to identify what this error is about. Any help would be appreciated.

More description,

> ProcessPCH++
>   /Users/sanket/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hello-bmfbxswcpcghlpfqacyvwgvzojza/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Hello-Prefix-ayovgewobfxhbwcxjzlegeqdrxki/Hello-Prefix.pch.pch
>   Hello/Hello-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 c++
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Users/sanket/Desktop/MyProject
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Comment: what's value of Linker flags in your project's build setting?

Comment: Blank. Haven't set anything.

Comment: Search your build settings for `-I-`.

Comment: already did the search. Found nothing like that.

Comment: Could also be a single `-`, which is than added to the full command. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11292606/1457385. Also make sure that there are no spaces contained in the path to your project (folder names).

Comment: Did everything mentioned. Still not working.

Comment: Remove - from your pch file name 'Hello-Prefix.pch' and try again